# Generacion de Excel con Apache POI, no escribe en la misma linea en diferentes celdas

Tags: excel, apache, apache-poi

actualmente me encuentro trabajando en la generacion de un Excel, esto lo realizo apoyandome de Apache POI. Me encontre
con un problema a la hora de escribir la informacion en el Excel, esto debido a que con el codigo que estoy realizando
no puedo escribir en la misma linea pero en diferentes celdas dos textos diferentes. 
Al final el resultado que busco es algo parecido a esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es el siguiente, en el mismo genere un par de metodos, uno que agrega una imagen y otro que agrega el texto deseado.
Como lo mencione, tengo inconvenientes al escribir en una misma linea pero diferentes celdas un texto diferente, ya que escribe
el ultimo que ingreso.

```
package pruebaExportExcel;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String imagenLogo = "../pruebaExportExcel/src/logo.png/";   

    /*Crea libro de trabajo excel en blanco*/
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    /* Crea una hoja nueva */
    HSSFSheet pagina = workbook.createSheet("Nueva Hoja);

    /* Crea el estilo para las celdas */
    CellStyle sinStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();

    /*Estilo para texto*/
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.AQUA.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

**/*EN ESTE PUNTO AL LLAMAR AL METODO, ME MUESTRA UNO U OTRO VALOR, SIENDO QUE NECESITO LOS DOS VALORES EN LA MISMA LINEA PERO EN DIFERENTES CELDAS*/**

```
    pagina.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2, 6, 0, 9));
    pagina.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(7, 7, 0, 8)); 

    agregaImagen(workbook, pagina, imagenLogo, 3, 3);


    generaFilasColumnas(pagina, 8, 0, style, "TEXTO1");
    generaFilasColumnas(pagina, 8, 9, sinStyle,"TEXTO2");

    try {
    /*Se genera el documento*/
        FileOutputStream salida = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/salida/ejemplo.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(salida);
        salida.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("No se genero");
    }
}

public static void agregaImagen(HSSFWorkbook workbook, HSSFSheet pagina, String image, int columna, int fila) {
    try {
        InputStream imagen = new FileInputStream(image);
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(imagen);
        int my_picture_id = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
        imagen.close();
        HSSFPatriarch drawing = pagina.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor my_anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor();
        my_anchor.setCol1(columna);
        my_anchor.setRow1(fila);
        HSSFPicture my_picture = drawing.createPicture(my_anchor, my_picture_id);
        my_picture.resize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se agrega imagen, detalle: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static String generaFilasColumnas(HSSFSheet pagina, int valorFila, int valorCelda, CellStyle estilo, String textoCelda) {
    /* Se crea una fila en la hoja, en la posicion de VALORFILA*/
    Row fila = pagina.createRow(valorFila);
    /* Se crea una celda en la posicion CREACELDA*/
    Cell celda = fila.createCell(valorCelda);
    /* Se asignan estilos a las celdas con el valor ESTILO*/
    celda.setCellStyle(estilo);
    celda.setCellValue(textoCelda);

    return textoCelda;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien ocupa. 
Genere un método que escribe en la misma fila en diferentes celdas, es una opción para resolver el problema que describí.

```
    public static String generaFilas2Celdas(HSSFSheet pagina, int valorFila, int valorCelda, CellStyle estilo,
        String textoCelda, int segundaCelda, String valorCeldaDos, CellStyle estilo2, float altoFila) {

    Row fila = pagina.createRow(valorFila); // Crea la fila
    Cell celda = fila.createCell(valorCelda);// Crea la celda
    celda.setCellValue(textoCelda);// Asigna el texto a la celda
    celda.setCellStyle(estilo);// Asigna el estilo
    celda = fila.createCell(segundaCelda);// Crea la segunda celda
    celda.setCellValue(valorCeldaDos);// Asigna el segundo valor
    celda.setCellStyle(estilo2);// Asigna el estilo 2
    celda.getRow().setHeightInPoints(altoFila);//altura de la fila
    celda.setAsActiveCell();

    return textoCelda;
}
```